# django SetPasswordForm and AdminPasswordChangeForm

Tags: django

hi im trying to use the above forms - but i get

```
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

i get to the form that it should show but it never save me the new password

i also needed to change the:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super(AdminPasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AdminPasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

since it doesnt get a user arg.

any ideas why?

thx

============================ edit =============================================

```
class set(FormView):
    model = User
    form_class = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'set.html'
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(set, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) 

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(set, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user_to_update'] = the user
        return kwargs
```

the init:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs['user_to_update']
    kwargs.pop('user_to_update')
    super(AdminPasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please show the complete traceback, and some code to explain 'and called them with form_class'. Why are you removing the user from the `__init__` method? The form isn't going to be able to set the user's password if it doesn't have access to the user.

Comment: Removing the user from the form fixes the immediate error but does not fix the problem. The form needs the user. You can [override `get_form_kwargs`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204710/change-form-fields-based-on-request/31205025#31205025) to provide the user to the form.

Comment: How form can possibly know which user's password it should change without sending user into form in some way?

Comment: i did what alasdair said and i saves the user that need to be changed but it doesnt get to the save method...

Comment: If it's not working, then update the question with the view. How can we tell you what the problem is if we have to guess what the code is?

Comment: Why override `__init__` and mess about with `user_to_update`? Just use the original form, and pass the `user` as it is expecting.

Comment: how can i pass the user? that was my first problem..

Comment: You can get the current user inside a method in  a class based view with `self.request.user`.

Comment: i got to the user through get_form_kwargs and it went fine but it still doesnt change the password

Comment: i pass user and not user_to_update.  i pass it to the built in django form and it deosnt change it. when i use my custom form whithout the init it get __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Comment: in the comment im talking about the current code, in the question its an old one.. thx for your help

Comment: Use the built in form. To save the password, you've got to call `form.save()` in the `form_valid()` method (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) for a similar example).

Comment: thx that did it!!! it just in my other form i didnt overridr form_valid and it saved me so it didnt come up in my mind to do so.. thx again!!

Comment: You often don't need to override form_valid() for `CreateView` or `UpdateView`, because the default behaviour is to save then redirect. With `FormView`, the default behaviour is simply to redirect, so you do have to override `form_valid()` if you want it to do anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the existing form. Overide the view's `get_form_kwargs` method to pass the expected arguments to the form, instead of changing the `__init__` method, which will break other things.

In order to save the password, you need to override the `form_valid` method and call `form.save()`.

For create and update views, you don't always need to override `form_valid`, because the default behaviour is to save the form and redirect. For `FormView`, the default behaviour is simply to redirect, so you do have to override it to get it to do anything useful.

```
class SetPasswordView(FormView):
    form_class = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'set.html'
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(set, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user_to_update'] = the user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(SetPasswordView, self).form_valid(form)
```